# In 'JTextFields', Is there any way to give choice to user to make TextField Editable. Default case is Not Editable. See Details.

Tags: java, radio-button, panel, frame, jtextfield

When user push a button (I created), it makes the **TextField** editable. 
First I use if condition in constructor as:
`if(button.isSelected())  TextField.isEditable(true); else TextField.isEditable(false);`
But, this gives me an error. Then I use the same statement (to give permission to user weather he want to make text editable or not) in a method with parameter `ActionEvent` in which is another method_implemented by `ActionListener`. But this also gives error. 
Code and output before applying action on button is given:
Code is given below
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeCsy.png)

```
package Radio_Button;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class Radio_Buttons extends JPanel{
    private JRadioButton bold;
    private JRadioButton italic;
    private JRadioButton both;
    private JRadioButton plain;
    private ButtonGroup group;
    private JTextField TextField;
    private JButton button;

    public Radio_Buttons(){
        //Declare all radio buttons
        plain = new JRadioButton("Plain",false);
        bold = new JRadioButton("Bold", false);
        italic = new JRadioButton("Italic", false);
        both = new JRadioButton("Bold+Italic", false);
        //Declare Text Field
        TextField = new JTextField("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",40);
        TextField.setFont(new Font("Chiller", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        //For button
        button = new JButton("Push to edit");





        //Add in panel
        add(bold);
        add(italic);
        add(both);
        add(plain);
        add(TextField);
        add(button);

        //Make a family of radiobuttons so they can understand each others. 
        group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(bold);
        group.add(italic);
        group.add(both);
        group.add(plain);


        RadioListener listener = new RadioListener();
        bold.addActionListener(listener);
        italic.addActionListener(listener);
        plain.addActionListener(listener);
        both.addActionListener(listener);

        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,500));
}
    private class RadioListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            int source = 0;
               if (bold.isSelected()) {source =Font.BOLD; }
               else if (italic.isSelected()) {source = Font.ITALIC; }
               else if (both.isSelected()){source = Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC; }
               else {source = Font.PLAIN; }
               TextField.setFont(new Font("Chiller", source, 30));

    }

    }
    public static void main (String [] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Quote Options");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Radio_Buttons panel = new Radio_Buttons();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `JButton` doesn't have any `ActionListener` in this code .

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing first. Spend some time to understand having meaningful "variable" names and [Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). e.g variable name like `TextField` is a no no.
2. In your example, `TextField` is enabled by default itself. Initialize it with "editable" as false like below:

   `TextField.setEditable(false);`
3. Add listener to your button and change editable of Textflied like below

---

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TextField.setEditable(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how I use prompt texts (Disappeared text) in JTextFields in my above program. Tell me the shortest method you have.

Comment: I did not get your question @umairmughal. What do you mean by prompt text (disappeared text)? Your textfield has quick brown fox... text in it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I want an empty textfield in which some text are written. But when user write somethings they disappear. Check link: https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=prompt+text+jtextfield&rlz=1C1CHBD_enPK745PK745&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-_f3wi6DXAhWElxoKHd9LBoQQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=637#imgrc=Wg5YLP-Mvo5CIM:

Comment: Basically you want placeholder @umairmughal call. 
 `Textfield.setPlaceholder("Your string")`. And it is always good to read the Javadoc first to look for any API